How to control a DC supply current using a micro controller
I am aware this question was asked before (How can I control DC current into a battery charger using a microcontroller?), but it was never answered, so I've added more information into this question and hopefully that will help in finding a solution.
I wish to limit and control the output of a DC supply for the purpose of charging a bank of 12V lead acid batteries set up in parallel.
I have a HP supply providing 24VDC at up to 200A.
I am providing the 24V to three Solar Chargers each capable of supplying up to 30A. So with them in parallel, they can charge at up to 90A.
As it currently stands, I am concerned that if I connect the chargers to my 600Ah bank of bateries when they are flat, the initial current draw may exceed what the solar chargers can provide and ruin them, so I want to be able to control the current from my DC supply to ensure that does not occur.
I also have other reasons for needing to control the current to the chargers in addition to protection, which requires me to be able to vary the current supplied from say 1A up to 80A through a micro controller.
I'm looking for a solution that is something that sits between the DC supply and the solar charger, so I'm not looking to modify the DC supply or the charger. I've already investigated modifying the DC supply to vary the output and it is too difficult a proposition due to the complexity of the supply.
Thanks,
Markus

If it's from a lab power supply, there's probably some method of remotely controlling that power supply that your microcontroller could send signals through.

Thanks. The power supply can't be varied, that was the first think I looked into :(

@Markus - Hi, Re: "I am aware this question was asked before" - please edit this question & add a link to the related question which was asked before. We want site members to be able to leverage & build on whatever happened on that question, to avoid wasting time starting from scratch again. If you can also explain what changed & why between then & now, so (again) site members don't spend unnecessary time doing a "diff" between that question and this one. TY (Also, if that previous question was "closed", then why is posting a new question better than editing the original?)

@SamGibson - The other post was not my post. I have also already answered your last quesion in my post, where I say I explain my question here in more detail than the other persons post, and therefore hopefully avoiding the same problem the other person had getting an answer because they didn't. There seems to be no escape from people who would rather fault posts than help answer them. Stack Overflow is a lot like that now too :(

@Markus - Thanks for replying. Re: "The other post was not my post." That's fine - please still link to it, as my point about wanting to leverage what's there still applies. It will also automatically add a link on the page of both questions, so readers of that (unsuccessful?) question can see a link to this (hopefully successful) one, so the previous one isn't a dead end. || Re: "I explain my question here in more detail than the other persons post" Understood, but until we see how the other post developed, we don't know how that one might be helpful with the extra you've added here. TY

Done. Though I don't think it will make any difference as both posts will appear when someone searchs for the same key words and they will look at both posts from the links provided from that search. a search which will also provide additional solutions not linked in this post.  Adding links to similar posts is something I've rarely seen and the more I think about it, it seems impractical, at what point do you determine another posts is similar enough to yours to link and how many links is enough or too many?

@Markus - Thanks for adding that link. || Re: rarely seeing links to similar posts - it happens often on this site! Feel free to ask the community on our Meta if you want to discuss.

@Markus Even if the related post appears as the first result in any sort of related searches, you don't want to add an additional step for those who may want and be able to help you. Many people are not eager to take the extra unnecessary steps because a questioner didn't care to include the necessary details. You should help people helping you, because we all have limited time and energy, and it shows your consideration for other people's time and energy. The "why should I include it for you if it can be easily found" is not the attitude you want to show to those who may want to help you.

@Markus You said "There seems to be no escape from people who would rather fault posts than help answer them.", and I have to agree with that part to an extent, as I have had a couple issues with such attitude myself, but in my case it was faulting the title of my post/question and voting to close it rather than suggesting an acceptable title. In your case, more details are needed/welcomed to help answering your question.

@Markus you say the previous linked question wasn't answered but it was. Read the comments below the question. The person found a workable solution but, never bothered to implant his words into a formal answer. So, what is this question about that's different to the previous question and, will the solution to that previous question also be suitable for you?

I see adding many link as spam and time wasting for people and adds confusion and congestion into a what should be a simple post. Each to their own I guess. Regarding the other post, it didn't find a solution for what it was titled, which is why I created this post.

You have not included the most important detail: what is the model of your solar chargers? Is there a schematic of their internal circuitry?
We have no idea what type of control they're using, nor of the control IC used, which is needed to figure out the way to implement a solution at the component level.
We also don't know if your solar chargers include current-limiting capability and some sort of an output or an onboard connection option for additional control.
You also did not include even a rudimentary drawing/diagram of your connections, nor a picture of your current setup.
What I can tell you without knowing enough details is that all chargers/converters with a regulated voltage or current on their output should have some sort of a negative feedback circuit.
By tapping into that negative feedback circuit, you should be able to set both the voltage and the current of the supply/charger.
Changing its output voltage limit can be as simple as changing one of the voltage divider resistors in the feedback, or adding a resistor in parallel to one of them: if you want to reduce the output voltage, you add a resistor in parallel to the upper resistor, but if you want to increase the voltage then you add a resistor in parallel with the lower resistor (this applies to a typical voltage divider feedback for positive voltage regulation with a TL431 and similar circuits).
You need to be careful in your calculations and make sure you don't exceed the limits of the circuit; many chargers have limits to how high or low they can go, before they shut off or become unstable.
Changing the output current involves a bit more:
you need to include either a current sense resistor with a voltage amplifier to bring its very low voltage up to the necessary feedback voltage value and then feed it to the reference/program input of the TL431, or you need to use some other current-measuring device like one of those Hall sensor ICs (like ACS712, ACS724, ACS770, etc.) which have isolated current channel from their sensing and amplification circuitry.
The current feedback can also be done by including a PNP transistor across the upper resistor in the feedback voltage divider, and then controlling it via a ground-referenced NPN which in turn is connected to to the current sensor coupled with an MCU.
Additionally, you might need to add an external power supply of 3.3V-5V for the feedback circuitry because an overload at the charger output will cause the current feedback to stop functioning if the voltage drops too low (like in a short-circuit situation).

Thanks for the reply. I reread my post and can see why you may have thought I was talking about modifying the DC supply and again pointed out all the important things I apparently left out. Which would have been correct, if I was looking to modify the DC supply or solar charger. Modifying the DC supply was not my intent. Not sure why you went down the path of solar charger spec's etc, it was never on the cards to modify the solar charger either.

I'm fully aware of how solar chargers work and the function of feedback systems in power supplies for regulation, they also incorporate significant protection, which makes modifying feedback in the supplies I have very difficult and time consuming to reverse engineer and also an element of luck if it will work in the end, which is why I am avoiding that option and have asked for help in finding a particular solution that avoids playing with either the DC supply or the solar charger.

There is no drawing/diagram necessary, the solution I'm after is a stand alone black box solution that takes in DC and outputs the same DC voltage but has the ability to control and limit the current drawn. Maybe dropping the voltage is an option as the two are linked, but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

An option might be to simply put a resistor in series, which is very inefficient and not that practical when I'm looking to use the high charge current I want, as well as making it variable. Maybe a switching circuit of sorts would work, using very low impedance FETs in parallel to deal with the large current? I don't know, which is why I'm here. I hope that's helped clear things up. Thanks.

@Markus OK, I get it now, you want another DC-DC converter in-between, woth MCU control capability. Can't think of a specific one right now, and don't have the time to find it. If I get a chance and cone across it, I will let you know.

That's correct. Maybe building a high current buck down converter would do it? Not an area of electronics I've babbled in before.
